# Can this relativistic hack allow one to see beyond an event horizon, in principle, else why not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, photons

Consider a lone photon. As its frequency increases, its energy increases. Taken to the limit, a sufficiently-high-frequency photon could be a black hole unto itself.

But the frequency of a photon is dependent on the inertial frame of the observer. Two observers could each observe this photon to be either above or below this critical frequency. Or, I could accelerate to "catch up" to this photon, red-shifting it until it is no longer energetic enough to be a black hole.

So couldn't I at one moment observe a particle to disappear beyond the event horizon, accelerate until the event horizon no longer exists, and hence observe what happened to the particle after crossing that threshold?

Is this in-principle possible? If not, why not?

**EDIT:** to clarify, I am not asking *how much* energy-due-to-photon-momentum is required to create a black hole, I am asking: *given* that threshold energy, how does the event horizon appear to different inertial frames which observe the photon to be above/below this threshold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much energy does a photon need to form a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141689/)

Comment: It cannot happen that one inertial frame sees a horizon but another doesn't, cf. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/50583. That this case is a  photon whose energy changes and not a mass whose velocity changes appears to be irrelevanat to me.

Comment: The Special Relativity works quite differently (and much more complicated) in the case of the elemental particles. How the GR works in their case, nobody knows. I don't think that an enough energetic photon would be a black hole, instead some quantum gravity effect will appear (similarly, as I think there is no singularity [i.e. point-like mass with infinite density] in the centre of a black hole). Now the problem is that the experimental physics would require $10^{15}$ times stronger accelerators to measure them.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/if-a-1kg-mass-was-accelerated-close-to-the-speed-of-light-would-it-turn-into-a-b?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: "*Taken to the limit, a sufficiently-high-frequency photon could be a black hole unto itself."* - a black hole has a rest mass and thus cannot have speed $c$ in any inertial reference frame.  A photon has speed $c$ in all inertial reference frames.

Comment: 1) Why must a black hole have a rest mass? The premise of my question is that it might not. 2) So a photon can increase the gravitational field arbitrarily without creating a black hole, right? Your answer might be a logical argument but it suggests no reason why such an object can't be created.

Comment: In GR the nearest thing to a photon would be a light pulse/wavepacket, and [the gravitational field of a light pulse doesn't look anything like that of a massive particle](https://core.ac.uk/download/files/200/4870147.pdf). Although this is a weak field calculation (I don't know of a full calculation) it's far from obvious that a light pulse could form a black hole. I suspect your question is based upon a false assumption.

Comment: PS I agree your question isn't a duplicate and shouldn't be closed